# Are there any possible methods for us identifying byte sequences which contains some plaintext?

Tags: algorithm

I want to implement one algorithm for automatically identifying some plaintext info from byte sequences. For example:

`6d 6c 70 00 00 00 01 d0 03 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 mlp..... ........
27 14 00 00 00 00 01 a7 e5 1a 00 2c 62 73 4a 30 '....... ...,bsJ0
52 63 63 44 4c 34 4a 76 4b 41 52 36 36 30 41 36 RccDL4Jv KAR660A6
77 7a 48 58 78 52 4b 52 58 57 50 42 4d 6f 77 4c wzHXxRKR XWPBMowL
52 34 6d 37 6d 57 67 3d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 R4m7mWg= ........
cc b5 4b d4 41 2e e4 42 48 c2 73 bf 2e 40 68 4f ..K.A..B H.s..@hO
28 9f 24 c0 c7 23 ab af 1d d2 f3 fb aa 15 01 c3 (.$..#.. ........
06 55 83 a7 c3 3a 68 1d 16 ee 7f 01 9a 51 39 1b .U...:h. .....Q9.
0a c9 64 2a 59 ad 4a e7 b9 af 7c 08 29 0c 1d 0b ..d*Y.J. ..|.)...
e9 39 9b d3 c3 3f 38 82 20 c7 d1 81 62 cc 7b 6f .9...?8. ...b.{o
5e 8c 45 ae 5d ec 34 09 2d ec 8a 33 7f 35 e5 05 ^.E.].4. -..3.5..
bf e5 77 7d c4 76 e2 2e 63 1e 21 ef bc 97 d7 df ..w}.v.. c.!.....
2a fb 25 df b0 54 e0 b8 4a 42 36 1f dd d1 7f b9 *.%..T.. JB6.....`

This hexdump data contains base64 encoded data,are there any possible methods for  me identifying this data which seems like plaintext from the byte sequences?

Comment: strings.exe - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/strings.aspx and similar

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. While the problem you ask might have it's use cases in information security it is by itself not an information security problem. Instead it is a general programming or algorithm problem which has  many use cases outside information security. Also it is not a problem of encryption, cryptography or even identity so all these tags should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say :) String can be an ASCII string, unicode string, byte string, whatever. It really depends what you are trying to achieve.

In case of base64 its easy, because just 64 characters are valid to be included in base64 string: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/, additionally there can be separator "="

So what you can do is to compare the data byte by byte and check if the byte matches one of characters in the defined character set. If so, add it to string, if not, print previously collected string, set it to empty and continue.

Another way is to use some tool as @TessellatingHeckler recommended. I would recommend it too because it is going to be un-achievable by your own when it comes to UTF or whatever else character encoding.

---

Edit: I forgot to mention that it will never be possible to collect valid strings only as some random byte sequences looking as string will not be a valid string in the end. Or you can come with some neural network ;) Humans can recognize it easily right? :)

Answer (score -1):

Yes there are.  The simplest, of course, is to look for keywords with spaces around them.

You'll want to OR the binary with a space character first to turn all the text to upper case.

You can look for [word frequencies](http://www.wordfrequency.info/free.asp) and [letter frequency clues](http://scottbryce.com/cryptograms/stats.htm).

On this subject I will refer you to the best writeup I know about, and it has to do with knowing the header formats of messages that led to breaking the Enigma code.

This really is a good read on the subject:

[Cryptanalysis of the Enigma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptanalysis_of_the_Enigma)